# Is it possible to Import a SIngle table(with data) from the whole database.sql file ?

Tags: import, mysql

I have a dump file of memory >1.0GB. It seems highly impossible to edit to take only few tables with structure and data. 
I know that exporting with only perticualr table. 
But, Is it possible to import only some table with "mysqldump" import and export query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try importing the whole DB and exporting the table(s) that you need, and then importing them again to a new DB.

Comment: But problem is, After some time while importing,It throws MySQL server has gone away, possibly because of Huge size.